# Python: Sort dictionary keys case-insensitive and return the dictionary in the same format unchanged

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python3 and I'm not fully aware of all its useful functions yet.

I have the following dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'david': ('18', 'Paris', '253-345-5434'), 'Joe': ('19', 'Dubai', '675-353-2345'), 'Luc': ('31', 'Istanbul', '766-673-3451')}
```

the dictionary keys are strings and each key has a tuple value that contains (age, address, phone number)
I tried the sorted method and it returned the following:

```
['Joe', 'Luc', 'david']
```

I want it to return ['david', 'Joe', 'Luc'] but I cannot find a way to do so. I need suggestions please!

Comment: since Python 3.6 `dict`ionary items keep their order of insertion, so you can just use `keys = list(my_dict)`, there's also the question of why you want them in that order

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
...
print(
    OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items()))
)
```

Comment: my interpretation is that they want a dictionary with the keys sorted.  that is what the title of the question says